# What was Varys trying to do at the beginning of S08E05?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the beginning of *Game of Thrones* Season 8 Episode 5, we see the following conversation take place:

> [DOOR OPENS]
>
> VARYS: And? Nothing?
>
> GIRL: She won't eat.
>
> VARYS: **We'll try again at supper.**
>
> GIRL: I think they're watching me.
>
> VARYS: Who?
>
> GIRL: Her soldiers.
>
> VARYS: Of course they are. That's their job. What have I told you, Martha? The  greater the risk, the greater the reward. Go on.They'll be missing you in the kitchen.
>
> [DOOR CLOSES]

TRY WHAT EXACTLY?!

I didn't think much of it the first time I saw the episode (hardly noticed in fact), but the second time, it felt like Varys was trying to poison Dany from the kind of conversation going on. Was he asking the girl to check on Dany to see if she is able to return to normalcy and eat or was he trying to kill her?  Did Daenerys know about this (the attempt to murder, not the spreading of the secrets)?

**Concern or Murder?**

Comment: Good question but I'd suggest it's deliberately *vague*.

Comment: Possible Duplicate, certainly related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100602/what-was-the-significance-of-varys-little-girl

Comment: Thank you, Ill keep an eye out for anything solid from the official sources meanwhile. I haven't found anything in this regard yet, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What was the significance of Varys' little girl?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100602/what-was-the-significance-of-varys-little-girl)

Comment: I don't mind accepting a duplicate and closing this question, but I just saw that the answer to the other question also includes the answer to this question. That question was "significance of Vary's little girl". Mine is related to "Vary's intentions". Wouldn't it be better to just edit the answer on the other question and change the answer to only answer the question (the answer was that the girls are not the same, one was used as Vary's little bird and the other girl was used as POV for KL's destruction) ? BUT if that is not suggestible and this question needs to be duplicated, I will do so

Comment: “Concern or Murder?” Can't it be both?

Comment: @GovindaSakhare While that question mentions the girl, it has an entirely different premise and is asking in all around different question really, primarily based on confusing the girl with another one in the episode.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### It is heavily implied he was trying to murder her.

Note the part of the conversation where he asks Martha what he's told her and she replies:

> **Martha**: The greater the risk, the greater the reward.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 5, "The Bells"</sub>

If all they were trying to do was feed Dany there would be no risk and she wouldn't be concerned about the soldiers watching her because it is their job.

On top of that it was already implied in the previous episode that Varys was going to attempt to kill her in his conversation with Tyrion. You've got to remember the facial expressions each character gives the other in the below conversation too.

> **Varys:** You know where my loyalty stands. You know I will never betray the realm.
>
> **Tyrion:** What is the realm? A vast continent, home to millions of people, most of whom don't care who sits on the Iron Throne.
>
> **Varys:** Millions of people, many of whom will die if the wrong person sits on that throne. We don't know their names, but they're just as real as you and I. They deserve to live. They deserve food for their children. I will act in their interest, no matter the personal cost.
>
> **Tyrion:** So, what happens to her? Please. Don't.
>
> **Varys:** I've spoken as honestly as I can. Each of us has a choice to make. I pray we choose wisely.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 4, "The Last of the Starks"</sub>

Comment: I presumed he would just let the entire westeros know that theres another Targ more eligible for the throne.. not plan a murder !! thank you for this. I will keep looking out for any official info, but it does seem implied that he was planning to poison her. This "The greater the risk, the greater the reward."

Comment: “I presumed he would just let the entire westeros know that theres another Targ more eligible for the throne.. not plan a murder !!” — when the less-eligible Targ had a dragon and the more-eligible Targ does not, you're gonna want a multi-pronged approach.

Comment: Not to mention that Varys is almost certainly guilty of arranging quite a few murders, and is complicit in many more. It's all but a formal job requirement for a medieval spymaster operating in decades of constantly changing leadership.

Comment: @Upper_Case it's actually an interesting case of [command responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_responsibility) (i.e. knowing what their forces were going to do, should Varys have stood idly by?). If he had been successful, many innocent lives would (likely) have been saved. It's like the attempts on Hitler's life. Had he been murdered in the early 30s then history might have played out differently.

Comment: @JJJ Varys was not at any point in the chain of military command. Not to mention, I doubt that Westeros has signed the Geneva Convention.

Comment: @Aron yea, it's more about doing the right thing. Eventually we get there anyway, but now Jon has to get his hands dirty. And you know what happens then, he'll probably want to take the black again.